# How to minimize Shopware 572 html cache?

Tags: caching, shopware

I have a problem with the Shopware cache. We moved from 5.3.6 to 5.7.2 (with the middle step to 5.6.9). After a few minor problems shop was stable and running. Soon we realized that the cache folder becomes huge (30+gb) and clearing the cache from the backend is not possible because the request never finishes.

After a small research, we found that var/cache/production34234234/html folder is responsible for this.

The shop is in production mode, cache setup is basic, cache enabled, and automatic cache invalidation is enabled. That's all. It looks like Shopware creates too many HTML cache files.

Did anybody have a similar issue and how to solve it?

Comment: do you have many customer groups or many different URL parameters? how long is your caching time? as there is no automatic deletion, the size could easily be reached, depending on the shop setup

Comment: @MichaelT Yes, there are 7 shops in the system, about 2 groups for each, auto deletion is on, caching time is between 1 and 4 hours. depends on the controller. Please give me some more info about this.

Comment: Turns out it was white spaces in cache/html files. Minify HTML options were disabled and files had a lot of spaces. now for 5h cache grow just to 2.2 GB. Much better. Where spaces came from I have no idea, not from the theme, that's for sure.